# Android : How to restrict disable sync

Tags: android, synchronization, android-syncadapter

In my android application I am using a sync adapter that will sync data with server in every 1 hour.I need to make this happen every time, but in the android setting --> Accounts --> my app there is an option for user to turning off the sync functionality, is there any way to restrict user from turning off the sync by this method.

Comment: there should be no way since the user should be able to disable sync if he wants. You may want to use regular service for that task, and just trigger it every hour instead of using sync adapter since it is maid exactly to allow user to choose if he wants your app to sync

Comment: Is there any way to find the status of sync .ie, whether its disabled by user or not??

Answer (score 2):

You can restrict disable sync. In your `syncadapter.xml` just set the `android:userVisible` to `false`. like this:

```
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:contentAuthority="com.example.android.basicsyncadapter"
          android:accountType="com.example.android.basicsyncadapter.account"
          android:userVisible="false"
          android:supportsUploading="false"
          android:allowParallelSyncs="false"
          android:isAlwaysSyncable="true" />
```

If you make userVisible to false then, users won't be able to disable sync from settings manually.

Comment: you are right,but when i do so sync  turns off.Why??

Comment: I think you should set `android:supportsUploading & android:allowParallelSyncs` to true.

Comment: sync is happening but its turned off in settings.

Comment: @KJEjava48 So the answer works? The user just cannot enable/disable sync?